# Need to add button in Outlook Ribbon Search Tab

Tags: search, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a task to add a button (Export) in Outlook Search tab, after instant search or advanced search i have to grab the result and export to csv file by clicking export button.

I am using VSTO with visual studio 2010 and office 2010.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: What specifically are you exporting from the results? The message contents, the search result view fields?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to place a button on the right place.
In your xml that will be returned to outlook, specify the right **insertBeforeMso** code to make sure your button is where you want it. Also find the right **idMso** for the tab you putting it to.

Here is an example of putting a button on main ribbon of email message window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" >
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
        <group id="Your ribbon group ID" label="Your button group Label" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard">
          <button id="Your button ID" label="Your button label" getImage="icon callback" size="large" onAction="click callback" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```